# How to control view state using an enum in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, struct, swiftui, enums, viewstate

I apologize if this is a silly question, I am new to Swift and programming to boot. I am trying to figure out how I can control my view state in SwiftUI using an enum. I am trying to keep my other view structs outside of `ContentView`, but the problem is I cannot figure out how to write to `currentView` to change its case outside of `ContentView`. For example, if I tap a button in `StartView`, how can I affect the variable `currentView`, which is in a different struct?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    enum ViewType {
        case start
        case settings
        case game
        case finish
    }
    
    @State var currentView = ViewType.start
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Group {
            
            if currentView == .start {
                StartView()
    
            } else if currentView == .settings {
                SettingsView()
                
            } else if currentView == .game {
                GameView()
                
            } else if currentView == .finish {
                GameOverView()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct StartView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("start")
        Button(action: {
            // How can I update my view state from within this struct?
        }, label: {
            Text("Button")
        })
    }
}
```

Any help or links to resources would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: use a Binding in your StartView. Look up how to use state and binding in the docs or in SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [workingdog commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68931354/how-to-control-view-state-using-an-enum-in-swiftui#comment121822370_68931354), just add `@Binding`s inside each of your subviews:

```
struct StartView: View {
    @Binding var currentView: ViewType
}
struct SettingsView: View {
    @Binding var currentView: ViewType
}
struct GameView: View {
    @Binding var currentView: ViewType
}
struct GameOverView: View {
    @Binding var currentView: ViewType
}
```

Then, simply pass in the `@State` to each of them. All changes made in each subview's `@Binding var currentView` will be synced to `ContentView`'s `currentView`.

```
if currentView == .start {
    StartView(currentView: $currentView)
} else if currentView == .settings {
    SettingsView(currentView: $currentView)
} else if currentView == .game {
    GameView(currentView: $currentView)
} else if currentView == .finish {
    GameOverView(currentView: $currentView)
}
```

Comment: Btw a [`switch` statement](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/0/10/switch-case) might be better instead of the `if else` chain.

Comment: Excessive use of if/if else causes the current version of the compiler to issue the 30s timeout error. Switch works.